# running gcc in cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I have installed *Cygwin* on my system. But when I try to use the `gcc` command it says:

`bash: gcc: command not found`

Can anyone provide me the solution, please?

Answer (score 17):

In my installation there was no generic `gcc` command either, so I made a symlink for it:

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-3.4.4.exe gcc
```

Now check if it worked by doing `which gcc` which should give you `/usr/bin/gcc` and then `gcc` should give you `gcc: no input files`. Note that your version of i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-3.4.4.exe may be different. Check in /usr/bin for it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe during installation of Cygwin you have not selected gcc, gdb and make packages.

I had the same problem and it was resolved after I selected above-mentioned packages.

Comment: The link is dead, If you could bring in the relevant steps if you still have them.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

- I always install the *whole* Cygwin package. Earlier versions had troubles with dependencies that are fixed now, I believe, but it's still a good habit. You never know when you may need the most esoteric bit of Cygwin.
- You may have to change your path. All the tools can generally be found okay if you're running inside the Cygwin bash shell but that's not necessarily the case from `cmd.exe`.

It's unlikely to be that last one since your error message is coming from `bash` itself, so I'm pretty certain that's how you're running it.

Have a look to make sure you have `/usr/bin/gcc` from within `bash` and that your path includes `/usr/bin` somewhere:

```
pax> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS

pax> which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

If it's not there, go back and re-install everything (or the relevant development package if you don't want everything). If it is there and your path doesn't have its location, change your path, in either `/etc/profile` or the equivalent in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another related issue that wasn't mentioned here, is from the command line the compiler needs the environment path variable updated to find the location of the c++ header files. In windows you can just update the path environment using the 'advanced system properties' GUI and add the location of the c++ include files. This will update the PATH environment variable in Windows cmd & Cygwin automatically upon restarting the shell.

To update your PATH from Linux or the Cygwin shell type... PATH=$PATH:/your_path_here Example:PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++ Also a good idea to add just the include directory as well: PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.3/include/ ...or check the proper directories for the location of your installation's include files, I recommend installing mingw for use with Cygwin, which is envoked with g++.

To install additional needed packages in Cygwin re-run the Cygwin install utility & check install from Internet to add packages from web repositories and add mingw-gcc-g++ & mingw-binutils. To compile your code: g++ hello.cpp -o hello

If using the gcc utility instead compile with the command: gcc hello.cpp -o hello -lstdc++ ... to get your executable.

As long as you have either gcc or mingw installed and the path to the c++ include files is in your path environment, the commands will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is another hard to spot mistake could also cause this error,

If your Makefile uses `PATH` as variable, the `gcc not found` error could happen.
This is because it changes the system path temporarily.

I took a lot of time checking the cygwin environment setting to discover this, so I'll leave it here in case this helps anyone finding their way here.